# explicit constructor of the wrong type called

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, c++14

In the following sample, my output is "single param ctor", twice.
My question is twofold, first, why is the bool ctor called rather than the version containing string, and second, is there a way to get the string version called without casting the call?

As an aside, my actual code doesn't call the constructors with hard-coded strings but with something like:

```
static constexpr auto NONE = "NONE";
Foo aFoo(NONE);
```

...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


struct Foo {

    explicit Foo(bool _isVisible = false): id(""), isVisible(_isVisible) {cout << "single param ctor" << endl;}
    explicit Foo(const string _id, bool _isVisible = false): id(_id), isVisible(_isVisible) {cout << "multip param ctor" << endl;}

    const string id;
    bool isVisible;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    shared_ptr<Foo> sharedFoo = make_shared<Foo>("hello");
    Foo regFoo("hi");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a limitation of C++ inherited from older C++ and ultimately from C.

Your string literals convert to `bool` better than to the "user-defined" type `std::string`.

Instead of casting in the call, you could add a constructor that takes `const char*`, possibly having it delegate to your existing constructor that takes `std::string`:

```
explicit Foo(const char* _id, bool _isVisible = false)
   : Foo(std::string(_id), _isVisible)
{};
```

This constructor will be an "exact match" (or close enough anyway) and prevent `bool` from stealing the limelight.

Or, since C++14, instead of the cast use [the `std::string` literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s), e.g. `"hi"s`, though you have to remember to do this at the callsite which is a bit "meh" for a general solution.

By the way, **if** you really want to take your `std::string _id` parameter by value, don't make it `const`; you're preventing it from being moved from and necessitating a copy in the member initialiser. Depending on what is going on at your typical callsite, the following may make more sense:

```
explicit Foo(
   string _id,
   bool _isVisible = false
)
   : id(std::move(_id))
   , isVisible(_isVisible)
{}
```

If you usually pass in an lvalue, though, at least accept a `const std::string&` to prevent one copy.

Comment: Shouldn't this awry nonsense of implicit *string-literal* to *bool* conversion having higher precedence be deprecated in C++?

Comment: @WhiZTiM: `nullptr` was introduced to help in some circumstances but, unless we change the type of string literals, or remove array-name-decay, or change how pointers work, we're kinda stuck with it. So `"foo"s` was then introduced to give us string literals that don't succumb to the problem .. but that's only useful when you're already aware of the problem! And if you are, then it's relatively easily solved at source anyway (as shown above).

Comment: @WhiZTiM: BTW the word you are looking for is "deprecated".

Comment: Interestingly, the exact polar opposite problem caused me big headaches when Boost 1.44.0 broke compatibility with changes to its `boost::io::file_descriptor_sink` constructors. I suddenly had `int` file descriptors being passed (as if they were pointers) to `file_descriptor_sink::file_descriptor_sink(const char*, ...)`. Yuk! Thank goodness for the `BOOST_VERSION` macro... Some libraries I use (which shall remain nameless) don't bother to tell you what version they are, and you're not always in a position to know what version you'll be building against, when you're writing your source code.

Answer (score 0):

> why is the bool ctor called rather than the version containing string

Because `"hi"` is <strike>a pointer to char</strike> an array of chars that is converted to a pointer to char (thanks, Lightness Races in Orbit), so a number, that i converted to a bool.

> there a way to get the string version called without casting the call?

Not really elegant, but... you can pass a second boolean param

```
Foo regFoo("hi", false);
```

to exclude the first constructor

Comment: `"hi"` is an array of char, but the type of the expression will decay to pointer-to-char pretty quickly

Comment: Or make it a real std::string literal in C++14:
`Foo regFoo("hi"s);`